# Palavra para «poll», em português europeu?

Tags: português-europeu, tradução, tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

Em português europeu, como se chama uma pergunta, feita a muitos indivíduos e com várias opções pré-definidas, das quais cada um dos respondentes escolheria uma?

> Caros convidados, escolham o prato que preferem para o meu jantar de aniversário. As opções que temos são:
>
> 1. Lombo assado;
> 2. Robalo grelhado;
> 3. Ou lasanha de legumes.

Como se chama isto?

- Um inquérito?
- Uma votação?
- Uma sondagem?

Em inglês, chama-se uma [*poll* (Longman Dictionary)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/poll_1):

> 1. [countable]    the process of finding out what people think about something by asking many people the same question, or the record of the result [= opinion poll, survey]:
>
>    - A recent poll found that 80% of Californians support the governor.
>    - Polls indicate that education is the top issue with voters.
>    - Labour is ahead in the polls.
>    - The latest public opinion poll showed that 25% of us consider ourselves superstitious.

Comment: «Enquete» não é usado em Portugal.

Comment: Já respondeste à tua pergunta. «Inquérito»/«sondagem» ou «votação», consoante o caso.

Comment: Mas um inquérito não é mais como um questionário? Isso não seria uma poll. Uma sondagem talvez seja, não tenho bem a certeza. (Senão não perguntaria.) E uma votação é mais abrangente. Em inglês há uma palavra especificamente para isto, e eu procuro essa palavra em português, @Artefacto .

Comment: As opções têm que ser pré-definidas?

Comment: Sim, @Jacinto , são pré-definidas: `Caros convidados, escolham o prato que preferem para o meu jantar de aniversário. As opções que temos são: 1) lombo assado, 2) robalo grelhado, ou 3) lasanha de legumes.`

Comment: Não me parece. Vê: [Open and Closed-ended Questions](http://www.people-press.org/methodology/questionnaire-design/open-and-closed-ended-questions/)

Comment: Acho que o teu endimento da palavra «poll» não está correto, mas isso será mais uma questão para outro _site_. De qualquer forma, a pergunta está formulado sem referência a essa palavra no 1.º parágrafo. E sim, é verdade que inquérito/questionário/sondagem não têm de ter perguntas fechadas (embora geralmente tenham, esp. _sondagem_)

Comment: Percebo que o meu entendimento de poll pode não estar correto. A minha pergunta mantém-se: **quero dizer** algo como «vamos escolher um fim-de-semana em Maio para ir acampar então; Carlos, tratas de fazer uma "**poll**"?» **sem usar palavras estrangeiras**.

Comment: @Artefacto `a pergunta está formulado sem referência a essa palavra no 1.º parágrafo`: está no título da pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

[*Poll* na aceção 1 do Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/poll_1), citado na pergunta, equivale ao português ***sondagem***, mas no teu exemplo eu usaria ***inquérito***.

Presumo que irias pedir a *cada* convidado que escolhesse o seu prato. Ora as *polls* e [***sondagens*** (ver Aulete 5)](http://www.aulete.com.br/sondagem) são feitas por [amostragem](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/amostragem): fazem-se as perguntas apenas a algumas  pessoas (a amostra) para se inferir a opinião ou hábitos da população a que essas pessoas pertencem. Mais ainda, nas sondagens recolhem-se opiniões, intenções de voto, informações sobre hábitos. Nunca ouvi falar de sondagens para pedir a pessoas para escolher algo, como no teu exemplo. Mas se tivesses, digamos, dois mil convidados, poderias fazer uma sondagem: perguntavas a uns duzentos escolhidos aleatoriamente o que tencionavam comer, para teres uma ideia do que ias precisar para os dois mil.

***Inquérito*** pode também ser usado com este significado. Veja-se o que diz o Dicinário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa:

> **5.** Estudo de uma determinada questão, social, económica, política..., através da recolha das opiniões, testemunhos, das pessoas. *À saída do supermercado respondeu a um inquérito sobre a qualidade dos serviços prestados*.

Por exemplo, o [*Inquérito ao Emprego* do Instituto Nacional de Estatística de Portugal](https://www.ine.pt/xportal/xmain?xpid=INE&xpgid=ine_publicacoes&PUBLICACOEStipo=ea&PUBLICACOEScoleccao=5685773&selTab=tab0&xlang=pt) é uma sondagem em que eles inquirem regularmente uma amostra de uns milhares de pessoas acerca da sua situação laboral (eu fiz parte dessa amostra recentemente).

No entanto, ***inquérito*** tem o significado mais geral de ‘ato ou resultado de inquirir’ [(Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/inqu%C3%A9rito), o que se aplica perfeitamente ao teu caso: tu inquires os teus convidados acerca do prato que eles querem comer. Um exemplo semelhante mas real é o *inquérito ao serviço docente* realizado anualmente na minha universidade, em que cada docente indica as disciplinas que está disponível para lecionar no ano seguinte.

Mas se quisesses servir um só prato, podias organizar uma ***votação*** entre os teus convidados para decidir por maioria o prato a servir no jantar.

Answer (score 2):

Com o exemplo que tu deste, eu diria que se trata de uma **votação**.

> Caros convidados, escolham o prato que preferem para o meu jantar de aniversário. As opções que temos são:
>    1. Lombo assado;
>    2. Robalo grelhado;
>    3. Ou lasanha de legumes.

A razão disto é que tanto em *inquéritos*, *questionários* ou *sondagens*, podem existir por vezes, perguntas de resposta livre, dando oportunidade a quem está a responder, de escolher a sua resposta.
Em relação a uma votação, esta tem como principal elemento, uma ou mais perguntas, em que cada uma possui um conjunto de respostas em que, segundo instruções de quem pergunta, poder-se-á ou não escolher mais que uma resposta.
É como se estivéssemos a falar de perguntas de escolha-múltipla, pois é nisto que se baseia uma votação.
Podes consultar aqui alguma informação adicional relativa a este tema:
[Definição de voto/votação](http://conceito.de/voto)
Não quero com isto dizer que os outros termos não sejam utilizáveis, apenas acho que neste caso concreto, o termo mais indicado é **votação**.